# Can i optimize my random numbers generator using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

this code `np.random.rand(1000, 2)` basically gives [one big cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9RPb.png) of numbers

[image]

But is there a way to get those random numbers generated between 4 intervals so that i can achieve something like these [4 clusters of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwjt8.png) instead?

[image]

Please note that the output format (list of lists) is important for me

Example of output:

```
np.random.rand(4, 2)

 [[0.20481852 0.39206741]
  [0.76406832 0.81779067]
  [0.94912136 0.9966882 ]
  [0.07224877 0.95471273]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn's [`make_blobs`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html), which randomly generates isotropic Gaussian blobs. For more control over then centers and covariances you could then look into [`multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=4, centers=4, n_features=2,
                   cluster_std=0.3, random_state=0)
```

---

```
print(X)
array([[2.19931109, 2.35193717],
       [1.95204867, 1.30826216],
       [1.9263585 , 4.15243012],
       [2.84382807, 3.32650945]])
```

---

For instance, for a larger amount of random samples:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=400, centers=4, n_features=2,
                   cluster_std=0.3, random_state=0)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. U did answer my question but i forgot to emphasis that i wanted the clusters themself to not be randomly placed but more 1 i each corner like in my second picture

Answer (score 0):

The example figure is the sum of two 2D random variables, which we can call `corners` and `2D uniform clusters`.  You can construct them using numpy primitives like this.

```
import numpy as np

# corner locations of 2-D uniform clusters
corners = np.random.rand(4, 2)

# scale of square 2-D uniform variates
scale = 0.3
square_rand = scale * np.random.rand(500, 2)

# select random corners for each item and add 
corner_ix = np.random.choice(4, 500)
four_clust = corners[corner_ix] + square_rand
```

Note the `scale` factor to reduce the unit-square uniform to 0.3 (measured by eyeball from your scatter plot).

[image: four clusters]

Version 2, which fits the image closer to your QPSK-looking scatter plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# scale of square 2-D uniform variates
scale = 0.3

# corner locations of 2-D uniform clusters
centers = np.array([[0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.8], [0.8, 0.2], [0.8, 0.8]])
corners = centers - scale/2

square_rand = scale * np.random.rand(500, 2)

# select random corners for each item and add 
corner_ix = np.random.choice(4, 500)
four_clust = corners[corner_ix] + square_rand

plt.plot(four_clust[:,0], four_clust[:,1], 'x')
plt.show()
```

[image: fixed corners, unif variates]

Comment: Visually the output in the second picture is exactly what i was looking for. But the problem is, as i read it, the numbers in "square_rand" are not directly mapped.
I needed the list to contain numbers that directly represents the plot in pic 2 since i want to work with the list. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The numbers plotted here are in the variable `four_clust`, which in this case is a 500x2 numpy array.  The scatter plot shows the zero'th column vs the first column.  `four_clust` is the sum of a scaled square uniform random variable with a four-point discrete random variable.

Comment: Also note that if you're synthesizing QPSK (which is what this looks like) your noise should be 2D Gaussian, not uniform as shown here.

Comment: Ahh the four_clust is what i was looking for. Thanks!